# Error with repetition which I can't spot

Tags: java

I'm trying to sort out some homework regarding "repetition" with the while statement. The homework is asking me to input a number and tell if said number is prime. So far, I've come with this:

```
class Prime {
    boolean esPrime(int n) {
        boolean prime = true;
        int divisor = 2;
        while (prime && divisor != n) {
            if (n % divisor == 0) {
                prime = false;
            } else {
                divisor++;
            }
        }

        return prime;
    }
}
```

Then I stated this "boolean test" in the main method to check if that piece of code worked:

```
boolean testEsPrime = esPrime(2) == false;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Prime p = new Prime();
    System.out.println("testEsPrime = " + p.testEsPrime);
}
```

And whenever I run it I get `false` and I can't seem to be able to spot the error. Any clue why this happens?

Comment: How could this possibly have compiled?

Comment: What happens in the code when you pass in `2`? Does the loop ever execute? Also, `2` is prime, so `esPrime(2) == false` will evaluate to `false`.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it executes, but it always gives me a false (with any number i input) thanks!

Comment: @Darkkurama It's working fine for me as-is (if not efficiently). Are you sure you're doing what you think you're doing? Is your check against `== false` throwing you off?

Comment: Ok, I've just checked what I had. I feel like an idiot. That piece of code is part of a longer file; I believe I got confused somehow and put that false there (I use to copy and paste those "tests" just for the sake of quickness, and forgot to modify it). Thank you very much all! ugh...

Comment: @Darkkurama Happens to all of us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the most efficient code in the world, but it works for me (see below). I'm not sure what the problem is here! Incidentally, you only need to test `2` and odd factors up to the square root of the thing you're testing, and a more efficient approach in general (for determining what numbers are primes in bulk) is to use a Sieve of Erastothenes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

The reason you get `false` for the test you do is that `esPrime(2) == false` *is* `false` - that is, `esPrime(2) == true`.

```
class Prime {
    boolean esPrime(int n) {
        boolean prime = true;
        int divisor = 2;
        while (prime && divisor != n) {
            if (n % divisor == 0) {
                prime = false;
            }
            else {
                divisor++;
            }
        }
        return prime;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Prime p = new Prime();
        for(int i=2; i<10; ++i) {
            System.out.println("esPrime(" + i + ") = " + p.esPrime(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

esPrime(2) = true
esPrime(3) = true
esPrime(4) = false
esPrime(5) = true
esPrime(6) = false
esPrime(7) = true
esPrime(8) = false
esPrime(9) = false

Comment: (Off-topic, but IMO since the code is the same, at the very least use a brace style that doesn't stretch it out so long, if it's necessary to include it at all.)

Comment: @Dave: The code's the same, but also formatted into a minimal compileable example. But I can redo the brace style if it bothers you.

Comment: It's just that a third of the code is wasted space, which for an example like this seems excessive. Especially since OP used the (obviously superior ;) style.

Comment: Lol don't even go there... ;)