# Determine if all the elements of array are prime numbers

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a java programme which determines if all the elements of an array are prime numbers. Here is my code:

```
boolean allPrimes(int[] ade){
        int i = 0; //counter
        boolean Prime = true; //initial boolean value
        while (i<ade.length && !Prime){
            if (p.isPrime(ade[i])) //function which determines if an int is prime.
                Prime = true;
            else
                Prime = false;
            i=i+1;
            }
        return Prime;
    }
```

I don't think this is correct as I've made some tests and they fail. What am I doing wrong? thanks

Comment: wouldnt it be ` while (i<ade.length && Prime){` instead of ` while (i<ade.length && !Prime)`. You are trying to see if all elements in the array are prime, but you stop iterating if you find a prime number. !true = false.

Comment: it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114442/error-with-repetition-which-i-cant-spot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You initialized the boolean Prime like this

```
 boolean Prime = true;
```

That means you never enter while the loop!  Initialize it to 'false' instead.
Your assignments inside if also are misplaced.

For your code to work - Simply change your second condition in while from

`while (i<ade.length && !Prime)`

to

`while (i<ade.length && Prime)`

Comment: I've tried this a while ago, but it seems to keep failing on the tests I made.

Comment: @Darkkurama Can you show us the failing test case and your isPrime method?

Comment: the tests are like this:  
    `boolean test1AllPrimes = allPrimes(ade_1) == true;
 boolean test2AllPrimes = allPrimes(ade_2) == false;
 boolean test3AllPrimes = allPrimes(ade_3) == false;
 boolean testAllPrimes =
   test1AllPrimes &&
   test2AllPrimes &&
   test3AllPrimes;`
where ade_1, ade_2 and ade_3 are:
    `static int[] ade_1 = {2, 3, 5};
    static int[] ade_2 = {1, 4, 8, 12};
    static int[] ade_3 = {1, 2, 3, 4};`

Comment: boolean testAllPrimes = test1AllPrimes && !test2AllPrimes
    && !test3AllPrimes;

Comment: sorry but I don't seem to understand why the " ? true : false;" although the tests now are true :) (I haven't learnt this yet in class I believe). Isn't it a way to not use this? also, as I reported in an answer with a for alternative that the execution time is really odd, the console displays an output 15 seconds after running the programme! why is it?

Comment: because this assingnment test2AllPrimes = allPrimes(ade_2) == false;   does not work! Check the result of System.out.printlin(allPrimes(ade_2) == false); this won't return true!  modify your test like this - boolean test1AllPrimes = allPrimes(ade_1);boolean test2AllPrimes = allPrimes(ade_2);
  boolean test3AllPrimes = allPrimes(ade_3);
  
  boolean testAllPrimes = test1AllPrimes && !test2AllPrimes
    && !test3AllPrimes;

Comment: I got this code, it's not efficient at all, but it seems to give true to the test cases:
while (i<ade.length){
            if (isPrime(ade[i])==false){
                isPrime = false;
            break;}
            i=i+1;
            }
        return isPrime;
    }

Answer (score 2):

Don't store the value in a variable at all. Do the loop and return false on the first non prime value you find (they can't all be primes if you've found one that isn't, no point processing any further), then return true after the loop (if you get there, they're all primes).

```
for (int i : ade) {
    if (!p.isPrime(i)) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: This seems to be the best way in terms of "efficiency". The thing is, when I try running the program, It kinds of freezes the console, and returns the output (boolean tests in the main) 10 seconds later, why is this happening?

Comment: I wouldn't know. The code I've written there should be fast unless p.isPrime takes long. You could always do `int i = 0; i < ade.length; i++` in the for loop and replace `i` with `ade[i]` as in your example, but it really should make no difference. Is the code I've provided the full contents of the method now?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Prime` variable initializes to true and in while condition `!Prime` means false.
Your while loop not executes and evaulates line return true.

Answer (score 1):

Building on what johnbk said:

```
boolean allPrimes(int[] ade){
        int i = 0; //counter
        boolean Prime = true; //initial boolean value
        while (i<ade.length){
            if (!p.isPrime(ade[i])) { //function which determines if an int is prime.
                Prime = false;
                break;
            }
            i=i+1;
        }
        return Prime;
}
```

That should work fine. Loop through the array, when you find a number that is not prime, set `Prime` to `false` and break out of the loop.

Comment: you don't evaluate `Prime` in the condition of your while loop, so you don't even need it here, just break from the loop

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Java guy but it seems to me your initial value for Prime should be false, not true, otherwise you'll never enter your while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You will never enter the while loop since `Prime = true;` and you're checking for `while(i<ade.length && !Prime)` which means `while (true && false)` (assuming `ade` will have some values in it)